# Need to create a context-free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need to create a context-free language for the following language.

$$L = \{w\in\Sigma^\ast \mid w = a^k b^m c^n \text{ where } k,m,n\in\mathbb N \text{ and } k<m \vee k>n\}$$

Here ^ is the empty string

```
S=  aAb | AbB | bBC | aTbBbc 
A = aA | aAb | ^
B = BbB | ^
C = cC | ^
T = aTb | ^
```

I got the following setup which accepts the words a,b,bc,bb,bbc,aabc,abbcccc, etc.., the only one missing is words in the form of "aaaaabccc", or where $k > m$ and $m > n$.

The problem is that I'm bound to 5 variables and 14 rules, but I can't figure out how to add a rule to detect the missing string into my current implementation.

Comment: Do you have $0\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Just checked, I don't. I'll have to modify the grammar to account for that.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31597/need-help-with-missing-rule-in-context-free-language - please don't do this, since it can lead to duplication of effort.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this works -

```
S = PC | Q
C = cC | ^
P = Pb | aPb | b
B = bB | ^
Q = aQc | aQ | aB
```

Thanks

Comment: You may need to explain before you get a +1.